# UITableView with image in cell stucks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I am developing an app which use UITableView,which contains cell having UIImageView of size 320 X 200.
This images comes from the web url and store to my app folder.Then i am showing this image to user.

For that i am using "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h" class's below method.

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSString *)url
   placeholderImageName:(NSString *)placeholderImage
           saveFilePath:(NSString *) filePath
              IndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                success:(void (^)(NSIndexPath *indexPath, UIImage *image))success
                failure:(void (^)(NSIndexPath *indexPath, NSError *error))failure {
    NSLog(@"DOWNLOAD IMG URL :: %@", url);


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setHTTPShouldUsePipelining:YES];
    [request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [self setImageWithURLRequest:request
                placeholderImage:placeholderImage == nil? nil : [UIImage imageNamed:placeholderImage]
                         success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                             [Storage SaveImage:image WithFileName:filePath];
                             if (success)
                                 success(indexPath, image);
                         }
                         failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                             if (failure) 
                                 failure(indexPath, error);
                         }
     ];        
}
```

when my all images downloaded to my local folder after that my tableview stucks while showing images.

Comment: It seems to me you are saving the image in the main thread. Here: [Storage SaveImage:image WithFileName:filePath];

Comment: use this library to download the images  and showing in the UItableview https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible that the downloading happens in sync with the main thread and is blocking it until the download has finished.

I use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) in my projects for this. It work's really really well.

**EDIT:**

OK, AFNetworking is doing all the work asynchronously and also caches all the images. See the [documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.2.0/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html).

If you don't need your success and failure blocks, you could go away with this.

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSString *)url
   placeholderImageName:(NSString *)placeholderImage {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    UIImage *pImage = placeholderImage == nil? nil : [UIImage imageNamed:placeholderImage];
    [self setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:pImage];        
}
```

Comment: It's not like that. I am facing problem even when my all images are downloaded and i have to just show it from my app folder.

Comment: There's no need to cache the images yourself. The documentation says it's automatically cached, and requesting asynchronously. see http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.2.0/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html#//api/name/setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:

Comment: try to use `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:`

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe the image is extremely large (that's independent of the UIImageView size).
Can we see your code?
Do you load them manualy from the file system? Probably is that, because you do that in the main thread. 
Try this in the code that loads the image:
NSLog(@"Is this the main thread: %d", [NSThread isMainThread]);
If you see 1, that's the problem. You can solve it using GCD (remember that once the image is loaded, move it to the main thread)

Comment: May I get the GCD code for this issue ? I don't have experience in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSOperationQueue for downloading image. While adding new item in NSOperationQueue, first check if it already added or not.

After NSOperation complete, that image will save into local.

Always load image from locally. If image not present in local then display some place holder.

Hope it helps.

Regards,
Punita

Comment: may i get the NSOperationQueue code for this issue ?

Comment: Here are some good examples what you are looking for:
1. [Advanced issues: Asynchronous UITableViewCell content loading done right](http://stavash.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/advanced-issues-asynchronous-uitableviewcell-content-loading-done-right/)
2. [iOS: How To Download Images Asynchronously](http://natashatherobot.com/ios-how-to-download-images-asynchronously-make-uitableview-scroll-fast/)

Comment: Also check image resolution when it download, Make sure If UIImageView have 40*40 then image size should be 80*80. If image is grater than 80*80 resolution and may table stuck while scrolling and load big image in cell.

Comment: @VivekShah if my information really help-full then please vote-up my comment. thanks